# How to add Routing Table Query-Result on pgrouting?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, wms, pgrouting

I've followed the pgrouting latest workshop http://workshop.pgrouting.org. I wanted to know how to add the routing table query-result into my webpage directly after the route showed up?

regards

Answer (score 1):

You can make a separate table or a view, then
1.) make a connection between PostGis and Geoserver and you can use openlayers or leaflet on youre website.

2.) export them to SHP file.